# moveUp and moveDown does not work inside a scope - CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, tree, behavior, cakephp-3.x

I'm using the tree behavior and everything works as expected when the scope's not defined, but I want to create multiple trees inside the table and do not rearrange the other trees when one specific node is moved.

Basically just rearrange the tree of that scope.

I'm defining the scope at my controller, inside the initialize() method (All my controller code should work with that scope) and moving the node as the documentation demonstrates.

```
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->Model->behaviors()->Tree->config('scope', ['column' => $this->passedArgs[0]]);
    }

    public function moveUp($id)
    {
        $node = $this->Model->get($id);
        $this->Model->moveUp($node);
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'otherMethod']);
    }

    public function moveDown($id)
    {
        $node = $this->Model->get($id);
        $this->Model->moveDown($node);
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'otherMethod']);
    }
```

After that nothing happens, neither the node is moved nor some other change.

Ps: Adding other objects to my tree work as expected, it only affects his scope and do not change the other trees.

Thanks for you time and help!

Comment: It is advised to always evaluate the return value of your operations, ie check what `moveUp()` and `moveDown()` return. Also check your `$node` entities for any errors (not sure if the tree behavior would set any errors on the entity, but having a look won't hurt). Also make sure to have a look at debug kit to figure what queries are executed. ps, please try to avoid stripping code down too much, your `initialize()` code is invalid as there is no `$value` variable!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, I've edited the code with your notes heheh, thanks again!
I've checked the moveUp return, it returns the node that I've passed to it without any changes, idk why it happens but only when I'm using a scope :/

Comment: Hey @ndm thanks again!!! I've used the debug kit to analyse the sql log and I've messed up with my parameters order. Now its working as expected LOL